# Can't submit Typo3 forms when not logged in

Tags: php, typo3

I have made a simple plugin with a form but it won't post when I'm not logged in.
Here is the file class.tx_gctest_pi1.php, created with Kickstarter.

```
require_once(PATH_tslib.'class.tslib_pibase.php');

class tx_gctest_pi1 extends tslib_pibase {
    var $prefixId      = 'tx_gctest_pi1';       // Same as class name
    var $scriptRelPath = 'pi1/class.tx_gctest_pi1.php'; // Path to this script relative to the extension dir.
    var $extKey        = 'gc_test'; // The extension key.
    var $pi_checkCHash = true;

    function main($content, $conf) {
        $this->conf = $conf;
        $this->pi_setPiVarDefaults();
        $this->pi_loadLL();

        if($_POST) {
            echo 'test';
        }

        $content='
            <strong>This is a few paragraphs:</strong><br />
            <p>This is line 1</p>
            <p>This is line 2</p>

            <h3>This is a form:</h3>
            <form action="'.$this->pi_getPageLink($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id).'" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="'.$this->prefixId.'[input_field]" value="'.htmlspecialchars($this->piVars['input_field']).'">
                <input type="submit" name="'.$this->prefixId.'[submit_button]" value="'.htmlspecialchars($this->pi_getLL('submit_button_label')).'">
            </form>
            <br />
            <p>You can click here to '.$this->pi_linkToPage('get to this page again',$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id).'</p>
        ';

        return $this->pi_wrapInBaseClass($content);
    }
}



if (defined('TYPO3_MODE') && $TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/gc_test/pi1/class.tx_gctest_pi1.php']) {
    include_once($TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/gc_test/pi1/class.tx_gctest_pi1.php']);
}

?>
```

This will output test when logged in and nothing when not logged in.
The page is reloaded but no post is sent

Comment: Looks like You should make Your plugin USER_INT.

Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293021/typo3-setting-plugin-as-of-the-user-int-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has not much to do with logged in / logged out. TYPO3 caches content unless you tell it to not cache.

`echo` `var_dump` `print_r` `debug` are methods that directly display things through php. TYPO3 doesn't catch them. If you want to have something displayed, add it to e.g. `$content` and return `$content` at the end of `main()`. The return value of `main()` gets cached.

You can try this by clearing your cache in backend and refresh the page. `echo` etc is displayed. after a new reload, it is gone.

So, how to solve this? There are a few possibilities

- make the page that contains your plugin uncached
- make the plugin itself uncached

I would suggest you find out what you really want to do and then write your code that is is using caching.

Comment: The plugin is just going to be a little form where the user writes their email addresses and the plugin will send them an email and store some things in a database. How can I make the plugin uncached?

Comment: This **does have** a relation to being (not) logged in. Your extension cannot work when cached because it's simply not being called. When logged in, TYPO3 disables caching and that's why it works. The solution is to disable caching of your plugin. See the link that Fedir posted as a comment to your question and see Mehdi Guermazi's answer.